# MySqlexception was unhandled, Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to add some values to table `tbllogs` after logging in, but I get an error

Here's my code

```
if (ctr == 1)
{
    Data.con.Open();

    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Success!", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From dbinfo.tbluser where UserName = '" + txtUser.Text + "' and UserPassword = '" + txtPass.Text + "'", Data.con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    Data.UserID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    Data.UserName = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    Data.UserLevel = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();

    string SaveStr = "Insert into dbinfo.tbllogs (LogsUser, LogsPassword) Values (@LogsUser, @LogsPassword)";

    MySqlCommand SaveCmd = new MySqlCommand(SaveStr, Data.con);
    //SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsID", Data.UserID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsName", txtUser.Text);
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsPassword", txtPass.Text);
    //SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsLevel", Data.UserLevel = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
    //SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsDateIN", timelabel.Text);

    SaveCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Data.con.Close();

    LoadData();

    Menu frmMenu = new Menu();
    frmMenu.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

I tried changing the line

```
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsName", txtUser.Text);
```

to

```
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsName", Data.Password = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString()));
```

but that didn't work either.

I will provide more code if this isn't enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: The inner exception usually gives more info.  You should never ever store passwords as plain text.  Why is the password being logged anyway?

Comment: ? The command is expecting a parameter called **`LogsUser`**. And you should not store passwords as plain text..

Comment: do a google search and read up on how to use as well as create `Parameterized Queries` also read up on how to use the `using (){ }` construct

Comment: A try-catch block might not be a bad idea either.....

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - why didn't you use **parameters** in your `MySqlDataAdapter`?? You **should** - always!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
   SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsName", txtUser.Text);
```

Into this:

```
 SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogsUser", txtUser.Text);
```

Also, as others have mentioned, you should not log the password as plain text.

Comment: geez, i didn't notice that, but Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

parameter name should be the same in sql query and c# parameter